# Can I build RPMs for two different platforms on one machine?

Tags: 32bit-64bit, rpm, rpmbuild

I currently have a Java application packaged in an RPM that gets built for 32-bit RedHat platforms, and I want to create a 64-bit RPM, which is largely just the same as the 32-bit one, but with a couple different .so files included.  All the Java stuff is the same on both platforms, so it's just JNI .so's.

**My question is:** Is it possible to have rpmbuild on a 32-bit system generate both the 32-bit and 64-bit RPMs (from different .spec files) since it's just repackaging already-built components, or do I need to build the 64-bit RPM on a 64-bit system?

N.B. I'm not actually building anything native on the system.  I'm just repackaging stuff that's already built.

... or vice versa, can I build a 32-bit one on a 64-bit system?  I really would prefer just to build and package this on one system than have two separate builds run for the separate RPMs.

Comment: You can definitely build both 32- and 64-bit on a 64-bit machine. I've done the opposite using a VM but I am not sure if that is required. I've heard you can use "mock" but never cared enough to pursue it.

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron stated you can build an RPM for multiple distros on the same machine (64-bit), but you have to be very careful or you can run into issues. The biggest problem I've run into is you build on RHEL 5, then you try to deploy to RHEL 6, since RHEL 6 has a different version of RPM installed, it can cause conflicts and fail to install. So in this scenario you have a few options:

1. Build the RPM on two machines, you've stated you don't really want to do this.
2. If you have the disk space, configure [Mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock), I've used it a ton before and it's really easy to get going as long as you have the disk space and the package spec was designed to pull in requires properly.

Personally I'd give Mock a shot, it's quite simple to set up, and will allow you to do what you want with minimal effort as long as the proper repos are available. In the event the build fails the log is pretty comprehensive regarding what the RPM build error was.